# JUJU botstrappin stuck on fetching juju releases 1.20.11 .... please help

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas

2014-10-31 00:58:21 WARNING juju.provider.maas environ.go:434 picked arbitrary tools &{1.20.11-trusty-amd64 https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.20.11-trusty-amd64.tgz 
file couldn't be found 
**ERROR code 1**

i'am stucking there since 2 weeks .. help me please

Comment: What steps have you performed to get this result ? Any other context information ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`wget -c https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.20.11-trusty-amd64.tgz`

`sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html/juju-metadata/tools/releases`

`mv juju-1.20.11-trusty-amd64.tgz /var/www/html/juju-metadata/tools/releases`

`sudo juju --debug metadata generate-tools -d /var/www/html/juju-metadata`

`sudo chmod 644 /var/www/html/juju-metadata/tools/streams/v1/*`

Now in your ~/.juju/environments.yaml file you will need to specify the URL of your newly shared tools:

default: maas

environments:

maas:

type: maas

maas-server: 'http:///MAAS/

maas-oauth:

tools-metadata-url: http://YOUR IP/juju-metadata/tools`